Understanding UX Differences: Creating User Personas for New vs. Existing Products
I often come across discussions about creating user personas for brand new products, but I'm curious about the UX differences when it comes to revamping an existing product. Specifically, I'd like to understand the nuances between creating user personas for a product that doesn't yet have a website (built from scratch) and one that already has an existing website but needs improvement.
For example, I'm working on a CRM application that has a website, and my goal is to enhance it and address current user issues. How does the approach to creating user personas differ in this scenario compared to starting from scratch?
Looking forward to your insights and experiences!

IMO the difference is real app usage data. You can use your current user's details to identify commonalities. Look at your onboarding flow and see what questions you ask to start analyzing your user base, if you don't have surveys identify what questions you can ask to segment your users.
Find out how these users use your product, what features they find most valuable, and what plans they subscribe to. That way you can look at company/user type, use cases, and spending power.
With new products its more common to create hypotheses that are tested as the product is built, used, and matures.
